# Failure in If loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Guys i was trying to solve Caesar`s cipher and I wrote a perfect code there is one problem making it not work and i will demonstrate it with a simpler code

```
var str ="abcz"
let x = str.charCodeAt(3); 
console.log(x) //=122
if(18<x<121){console.log("Too young")}   // it always goes to this function even if i get the code of a,b,c
else if(x>121) {console.log("zaza")} //it never reaches this point
```

if someone can help explain why this code works like this to me I would be grateful
Thanks in advance

Comment: `18<x<12` this doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: `18<x<121` is `(18 < x) < 121` which is either `true < 121` or `false < 121` which are `1 < 121` or `0 < 121` respectively, which is always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this instead

```
var str ="abcz"
let x = str.charCodeAt(3); 
console.log(x) //=122

if(18 < x && x < 121){console.log("Too young")}   

else if(x>121) {console.log("zaza")}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the JS interpreter first evaluates `if (18 < 122)` to `true` and then `if (true < 121)` to `true`. My assumption is that `true` is converted to `1` to make a numeric comparison with `121`.
Your condition should look something like this `if (x > 18 && x < 121)`